# Can I share my Google Photos to Instagram using my iPhone?

Tags: instagram, google-photos

I have a bunch of photos in Google Photos that I would like to share to Instagram using my iPhone. Is there a way to do to that? Or a way to move photos from Google Photos to Photos on my iPhone? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

From Google's support document for [sharing photos and videos from Google Photos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6131416?hl=en&ref_topic=6128855&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1):

> Open the Google Photos app.
>
> Tap the photo, album, or movie to share.
>
> Tap the Share button (bottom-left).

From there, to save to your device, tap Save Image on the middle row.

To upload to Instagram, tap More (bottom-right button) and Instagram should appear as an option in the second row of icons up from the bottom. (If it doesn't, scroll that row all the way to the right, then tap More, and tap the button across from Instagram to turn it on. Tap Done at the top, then tap Instagram.)

Comment: Thanks very much. As I was using your suggestion, I realized I could take a screen shot of my googlephoto photo. It winds up in iPhone photo and I can use it as I need to from there. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Not to be critical but I have never understood the idea of taking a screenshot of a picture that can be directly saved to the device. You're certainly not the first person I've seen that's done it. I just don't understand it lol

Comment: Hi! I know! It sounds crazy. But I took the photos with a different device and was using googlephoto at the time for backup. There are certain photos from that era that I want to share or use now and I cannot get the photos to transfer from googlephoto to iPhone photo. And if you want to post photos to instagram, it is done via phone. Man! if you know a way to get it done another way, I'd love to hear it, which is why I posted my question here. Peace.

Comment: The steps I listed don't work?

Comment: Hi tubedogg: I just got to thinking I could maybe go a lazier way...no reflection on your helpful suggestion, more a statement of my attitude. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JanNadine I know this is 5 years later, but you should probably mark this as the correct/accepted answer since it does work.